# how to create margin in canvas using jsPDF

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

Hi I'm generating pdf from html by using jdPDF, but unfortunately I'm not able to give page margin. Any help would be appreciated. How I can add margin into my page by using canvas object.

Here is source code.

```
    $(function(){
    //$("#button1").click(function(){
        console.log("hey");

        $( "#other" ).click(function() {
            //alert("hello");

        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        source = $('#fromHTMLtestdiv');

        var canvas = pdf.canvas;
        canvas.height = 72 * 11;
        canvas.width=72 * 8.5;;

       // var width = 400;

        document.body.style.width = 400 + 'px';
        document.body.style.margin = 30 + 'px';

        //source.css("border","1px solid");

        html2pdf(source, pdf, function(pdf) {                
                //var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
               // iframe.setAttribute('style','position:absolute;right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:100%; width:500px');
              //  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
              //  iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');

              window.location = pdf.output('datauristring');

               //var div = document.createElement('pre');
               //div.innerText=pdf.output();
               //document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
        );
    //});

    })
    });
```

May I getting right approach? here is the link of image with problem

http://screencast.com/t/50UMjHImD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a lot of time trying to add margin, add styles or making tables with jsPDF. To me it's a bit complicated so I looked after another one and I found : [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/index.html#/). You will have no problem to add margin since the styles are really easy to define. 
Hope this will help even if i'm not really answering the question.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me... but the only problem is how can I assign background color in  even and odd row in table or background color in table header.

Comment: I tried `background : red` but it applies the background color only on the text and not in the entire cell... So it seems like it's not possible for the moment but don't forget to check next releases of the plugin, the developper might add some features as he said on his website.

Comment: I found out how to change the background color of a cell. You can add fillColor : red or fillColor : #ddd in your style and it will work. Sorry for the late answer but I hope this will help :)

Comment: Hey hi, Thank you very much for reply Alex. its nice to see you message. ok I will check. But again thank you very much for reply.